# What is the purpose of adding routes for additional new actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

The guide *Rails Routing from the Outside In* has a section named [*Adding Routes for Additional New Actions*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-routes-for-additional-new-actions) in chapter 2, *Resource Routing: the Rails Default*, with this example:

```
resources :comments do
  get 'preview', on: :new
end
```

which generates the following route:

```
             Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
preview_new_comment GET    /comments/new/preview(.:format) comments#preview
```

The same result can be achieved at least in two other ways:

1) Adding a collection route inside `resources :comments` like `get 'new/preview', to: :preview, on: :collection` (if you don't bother about the route name)

2) Adding just this route to the corresponding singular resource:

```
resource :comment, only: :preview do
  get 'new/preview', to: :preview, as: 'preview_new', on: :collection
end
```

which has exactly the same behavior.

So why there is a `on: :new` option? Is it just a shortcut? If it is, why it's just for 'new actions' and there are not any similar options for the other default REST actions, like `on: :edit` or `on: :delete`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a shortcut that is unique to the RESTful action new, in which an object is instantiated but not yet persisted.

For example, if you are filling out a form for a new object, you would provide yourself with a link_to "preview", which sends all of the attributes to your preview action (instead of directly to create). This is similar to a show view, but for an object that only exists in memory.

This functionality isn't logical for destroy, update, index, show or create. I suppose you could use a preview on an edit action after assigning new attributes before sending to update, but you'd have to create the route manually.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a subtle difference.

If you add it to the `resources :comments` the path helper generated has a pluralized resource name so it will be `preview_new_comments` and the path will be `/comments/new/preview`. If you add it to the corresponding singular resource it doesn't pluralize the resource name in the path so you get `/comment/new/preview` but the helper will be `preview_new_comment`. Using `:on` will generate the path helper with the singular resource `preview_new_comment` but the route will have the pluralized resource `/comments/new/preview`.

To get the same behaviour you could use the following more verbose route outside the resource

```
get 'collections/new/preview', to: 'collections#preview', as: :preview_new_comment, on: :collection
```

I'm not sure why there is no `on: :<action other than new>` option. They advise against having too many new actions in the documentation but if you are going to have a new 'new' it seems a reasonable possibility you might need an new 'edit' to edit your new 'new'. However, things become more complicated because to edit you would need a path like `collections/<id>/edit/preview` and the path helper of the solution above stops working as you might expect. More importantly at this stage maybe you start veering away from the original intention of the option.